# Android navigationView.getMenu() setVisible(false) but just invisible the text (still with space)

Tags: android

I tried to `navigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.nav_login).setVisible(true)` but just invisible the text (still with space).

How to complete invisible the menu item?

Thanks,
Joe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this**

1) setVisible(View.INVISIBLE) - View is invisible to user

2) setVisible(View.GONE) - View & respective space is gone

3) setVisible(View.VISIBLE) - View is visible to the user

Comment: it can't, and warn setVisible(boolean). It seems it only accept true or false